# Removing the "shine" in icon with Flex Builder

Tags: ios, iphone, flash, apache-flex, flex4

Is it possible to remove the App store's icon "shine" using Adobe Flex Builder?

Comment: Could you be more clear? Why do you want to edit an image in an IDE?

Comment: I know you can remove the launch icon in xcode using UIPrerenderedIcon but don't know how to do it in the Flash environment

Answer (score 0):

UIPrerenderedIcon is a key in the Info.plist file. I'm guessing that this file also exists in the Flash Environment since it's required for the app to work.

Answer (score 0):

As @Randall and others have stated, you can achieve that modifying the application descriptor xml (YourApp-app.xml) adding the following block to it:

```
<InfoAdditions> 
    <![CDATA[ 
        <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key> 
        <true/> 
    ]]> 
</InfoAdditions>
```

You can read more in the [adobe docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac1e63e3d129907d2886-8000.html).